# Javascript Regex to limit Text Field to only Numbers and only10 or 12 digits

Tags: javascript, regex

i want a javascript regex for my input that accept only numbers with 10 or 12 digits.
forexample:

1234567890 => True

a12345678u =>False

123456789123 =>True

sj231@ => False

aq123456789t =>False

i very very appreciate if any one can help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try: `[0-9]{10}([0-9]{2})?`

```js
const regex = new RegExp("[0-9]{10}([0-9]{2})?");

console.log(regex.test('1234567890'));
console.log(regex.test('a12345678u'));
console.log(regex.test('123456789123'));
console.log(regex.test('sj231@'));
console.log(regex.test('aq123456789t'));
```

[regex101](https://regex101.com/) explanation:

[image]