# how to correctly use Yup/formik number validation ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, numbers, formik, yup

I would like to explain my problem of the day.

I'm using a simple number type validation

```
number: Yup.number()
.required("Required")
.max(100000000, "To big")
.min(0, "Not negative number")
```

my problem is ,in the entry of the field, I can add only one letter the "e", I do not understand why

example "12e3"

while I would like to enter only numbers

example "123"

if you have any ideas, thank you

Neff

Comment: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/10/react-validation-formik-yup/
see following article

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is more than one way to achieve your only number input.
The problem is not yup.

1. check your input before sending. Exclude using [ASCII](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7295864/17925238)
2. check your input before sending. Exclude using [Regex1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43688362/17925238) or [Regex2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68694477/17925238)
3. change your input form type to number from [basic html](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number)

Answer (score 1):

You can't handle it with Yup. because "e" interprets as number. in math "e" is a way to represent scientific notation. You can use react-number-format for handling this.

Comment: thank you very much for your solution, my I would like to find another way than to have to by a  library

Answer (score 0):

Use this condition, it's take care of "e".

```js
const digitsOnly = (value) => /^\d+$/.test(value)

Yup.object().shape({
           mobile: Yup.string().required('please_enter_mobile').test('Digits only', 'digits_only', digitsOnly).min(7,'please_enter_valid_mobile').max(15, 'Maximum number limits')
        }).required()
```